# Including javascript in node js project jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to include javascript on a page written in jade template. I wrote it like this : `script(src='/public/javascripts/scr1.js')`
and the script is in that directory.
and in the script I wrote `alert("doesnt work");` and I see it doesnt go into the script
Anyone knows how to properly inlcude js?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify `/public`. Just do `script(src='/javascripts/scr1.js')`

Comment: You're welcome. If you're satisfied with the answer, please select this as the chosen answer.

Comment: I have 1 more question to ask now. In my js i load a jade page into div of another jade page using $("#div").load("dir") , in the dir i wrote the directory of the jade page i want to load but it only says CANT GET/ page1.jade. Do i need to do something in my app.js?

Comment: @asasdasd If I got your question correctly, you will have to convert jade to HTML first in order to load it.